# Neo4j: Converting REST call output to JSON

Tags: rest, neo4j

I have a requirement to convert the output of cypher into JSON.

Here is my code snippet.

```
RestCypherQueryEngine rcqer=new RestCypherQueryEngine(restapi); 
String nodeN = "MATCH n=(Company) WITH COLLECT(n) AS paths RETURN EXTRACT(k IN paths | LAST(nodes(k))) as lastNode";
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> queryResult = rcqer.query(searchQuery);

    for(Map<String,Object> row:queryResult)
    {   
        System.out.println((ArrayList)row.get("lastNode"));
    }
```

Output:

[http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/445, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/446, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/447, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/448, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/449, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/450, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/451, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/452, http://XXX.YY6.192.103:7474/db/data/node/453]

I am not able to see the actual data (I am getting URL's). I am pretty sure I am missing something here.

I would also like to convert the output to JSON.

The cypher works in my browser interface.

I looked at various articles around this:

[Java neo4j, REST and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920763/java-neo4j-rest-and-memory)
[Neo4j Cypher: How to iterate over ExecutionResult result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650948/neo4j-cypher-how-to-iterate-over-executionresult-result)
[Converting ExecutionResult object to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618102/converting-executionresult-object-to-json?answertab=active#tab-top)

The last 2 make use of EmbeddedDatabase which may not be possible in my scenario (as the Neo is hosted in another cloud, hence the usage of REST).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand what you're doing? Your query does not make sense at all.
Perhaps you should re-visit the online course for Cypher: http://neo4j.com/online-course

```
MATCH n=(Company) WITH COLLECT(n) AS paths RETURN EXTRACT(k IN paths | LAST(nodes(k))) as lastNode
```

you can just do:

```
MATCH (c:Company) RETURN c


RestCypherQueryEngine rcqer=new RestCypherQueryEngine(restapi); 
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> queryResult = rcqer.query(query);

for(Node node : queryResult.to(Node.class))
{   
    for (String prop : node.getPropertyKeys()) {
      System.out.println(prop+" "+node.getProperty(prop));
    }
}
```

I think it's better to use the JDBC driver for what you try to do, and also actually return the properties you're trying to convert to JSON.

Comment: I totally understand the Cypher query is work of fiction & there is no need for redoing the online course. The logic I have utilizes extract & reduce - all I was checking is a simple method to convert the same into JSON (since I have not found any evidence of documentation in this area). I will try the same, using jdbc. thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, the jdbc call does work thanks.